# Entry type for "..." is not defined in the style file

Tags: bibtex

Hello I have another problem which I can't solve. I output my bibliography in the following way:

```
\bibliographystyle{copernicus}
\bibliography{bibl.bib}
```

and get the warning: `entry type for "..." isn't style-file defined.` But this only happens with entries that start with @software or @online, like:

```
@online{prarmodel,
  author = {University of Wisconsin-Madison},
  title = {MIMIC TPW vers.2},
  year = 2022,
  url = {http://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/mtpw2},
  urldate = {2022-07-21}
}
```

How can I solve the problem? Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the bibliographystyle :(

Comment: It is not an error but a warning, bibtex will use a default. Check the output, and if it isn't to your liking use a different bibliographystyle.

Comment: Hello Thank you, but the results are not displayed, because this is a template of a paper in which I want to publish, it is unfortunately not possible to change the bibliographystyle.

Comment: then ask who ever gave you that template and the style how online sources should be inserted.